# Проверка PlayerPrefs.HasKey по типу String не реагирует. Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть переменная Nickname типа string и десяток переменных типа int.
Все они прекрасно записываются в реестр и там отображаются, но при попытке подгрузить значения из реестра проверка
`if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Nickname"){}`
Просто не реагирует, словно такого имени в реестре не существует. Если же проверять любую переменную int, то условие соблюдается.
И было бы как-то пофиг, ибо всё сохраняется и подгружается разом, НО!
На string юнити не реагирует вообще! Даже при прохождении проверки на int или же вовсе без неё, текстовое поле изменение игнорирует. На сцене есть InputField, куда и должны вписываться значения при загрузке сцены, но он остаётся пустым, при том что числовые переменные вписываются без проблем.

Comment: Ошибка в коде..

Comment: Возможно вы путаете значение с ключом

Comment: логами выяснил то, что значение записывается в реестр в исходном виде, но при загрузке из реестра приходит пустая строка.